# Can you use Uncanny Dodge against extra damage effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

When a Rogue activates their Uncanny Dodge against extra damage effects, does the feature halve all of the damage or only the weapon's damage?

To exemplify, if struck by a Planetar's great sword, the Rogue takes 4d6+7 slashing damage plus 4d8 radiant because of Angelic Weapons. Does Uncanny Dodge half all of that damage or only the great sword portion?

Answer (score 17):

## All Damage!

Uncanny Dodge states, emphasis mine (PHB, 96)

> You can use your reaction to halve **the attack's damage** against you.

This is for ALL damage from the attack, not just the Melee weapon damage.